# Is there a standard character encoding that is ASCII minus control characters?

Tags: encodings

I came across some unusual strings in some embedded SH2A code I'm analyzing....

`11 53 54 00 53 55 4E 44 41 59 00 4F 46 00 2E 4F 56 45 4D 42 45 52
 .  S  T  .  S  U  N  D  A  Y  .  O  F  .  .  O  V  E  M  B  E  R`

Which I realized is just "1st sunday of November" if you subtract 0x20 from each byte, effectively removing the control characters from ASCII. But they're still using a full 8 bits per character (not that subtracting the control characters is enough to drop a bit anyway) so I'm left wondering why they would do it and whether it's something homegrown or just obscure.

Comment: Even minus control characters it doesn't explain why the ASCII `1` is converted to a `.` ... also the `N` of November. That doesn't fit into a scheme that is merely "flattening" all control characters, does it?

Comment: @0xC0000022L That's not a `.`, it's a `\x11`.

Answer (score 1):

the implementations of tolower() , toupper() normally tend to use the addition or subtraction of 0x20  maybe it is some kind of homegrown brew of these functions

here is a msvcrt toLower() pseudo c code from radare2

```
[0x78b0ccd4]> pdc
function sym.MSVCR100.dll__tolower () {
    //  1 basic blocks

    loc_0x78b0ccd4:

       edi = edi
       push ebp
       ebp = esp
       eax = dword [arg_8h]     //[0x8:4]=-1 ; 8
       eax += 0x20
                                //ebp ; ebp
       return
(break)

}
[0x78b0ccd4]>
```